# display subtitles for mp3 using php

Tags: php, mp3, subtitle

I have a mp3 file, and a text file which contains the words that speech on mp3. And also i have a srt file corresponding to the mp3. Now I want to display the subtitles for the mp3 using php .I don't have any idea about this. So Please help me for solving this task.

Answer (score 0):

You should solve this with Javascript and not PHP.

Checkout this awesome library. http://captionatorjs.com/, you can insert .SRT file to display as caption/subtitle.